# GPS continuosly localize in version 2.3.5 (not in 2.2)

Tags: android, gps, location, version

I have a program that employs GPS to localize a person every 2 minutes. For that, the code is:

```
private boolean flagLocalizacion = false;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private Location ultimaLocalizacion;
private LocationManager locationManager;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationListener = new LocationListener() { 
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location!=null) {
                if(ultimaLocalizacion == null && flagLocalizacion) {
                    ultimaLocalizacion = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude() + "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if ((ultimaLocalizacion.getLatitude() != location.getLatitude()
                            || ultimaLocalizacion.getLongitude() != location.getLongitude()) && flagLocalizacion) {
                    ultimaLocalizacion = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude() + "Latitude: "  + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }                   
            }
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            System.out.println("gps");
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            System.out.println("No gps");
        }
    };                                                                   Button botonComenzar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bComenzar);
    botonComenzar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 12000, 30, locationListener);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activada Localizacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            flagLocalizacion = true;    
        }
    });
```

My problem is:

This applicaction works correctly in version 2.2. But the software failed when I installed it in a phone that has 2.3.5., the  The fail is that localice continually, not every 2 minutes. Do you have thoughts on why that is happening?

Thanks you.

Comment: First of all, isn't 2 minutes = 120000ms and not 12000ms? 12000ms = 12s  if my Math is right.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous GPS refresh (i.e., with an interval between GPS updates of 1 sec), regardless of the requested minTime, is a known issue with many Android phones prior to JellyBean.

Full discussion of this issue with the Android team is here:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/34230/

A new CTSVerifier test has been added in Android 4.1 JellyBean that should prevent this from happening on JellyBean and higher.

For devices pre-Jelly Bean that are affected by this, your only option for a workaround is to manually unregister and re-register the LocationListener at whatever time interval you want GPS to refresh.